# Scrapy Crawling but not Scraping

Tags: scrapy

I am scraping a set of ~10,000 links in the same domain with identical structure using scrapy runspider command. Randomly in between some pages (a significant ~40% to 50% pages) are Crawled but Not scraped, because in my parse method I evaluate a particular element in the page, based on which I scrape the other elements of the page. But as it goes for some Reason (more on this Reason later), for some of the urls that element evaluates incorrectly. To fix this I want to call my parse method for these urls repeatedly up to a maximum of say 5 times till it evaluates correctly (hoping that in 5 runs the page will respond correctly to the condition or otherwise I assume that the element is genuinely evaluated as wrong). How to code this (part code below)?

Possible Reason for the above behaviour: my weblinks are of the type 
www.example.com/search_term/ which are actually dynamically generated page after entering "search_term" in www.example.com. So my guess is that in several cases Scrapy gets the response even before the page www.example.com/search_term/ is fully generated. Maybe the ideal solution is to use a webdriver and all, but all of that will be too complex for me at this stage. As long as I get 95% scraping, I am happy.

Relevant Code below (sanitised for readability without leaving out any details):

```
class mySpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "spidername"

def start_requests(self):
    urls = [url1, ... url10000]

    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse,headers={
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B179 Safari/7534.48.3"})

def parse(self, response):
   if (value of particular_item in page == 10): 
     yield {'someitem':       
           response.xpath('/html/body/div').extract())}
   else:
     <<Once again call this parse fuction with the same url upto a       maximum of 5 times - Need help in writing the code here>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath requires that the `body` of the HTML you are parsing has a `div` as first element:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>...
```

Are you sure every site looks that way? Without any information on *what* you try to scrape I cannot give you more advice.

Alternatively you can try another solution where you extract all the `div`s from the website:

```
for div in response.xpath('//div').extract():
    yield {'div': div}
```

Comment: The list of sites are essentially search results of various possible queries like:

Comment: ... (sorry, completing above query)...                                                      ...possible queries like:
    www.exapmle.com/abcd/
    www.exapmle.com/shjk/ 
    www.exapmle.com/dued/

Hence the same structure. The success of scraping the other 60% pages is further proof that the xpaths are correct. And also ind different runs different links are missed, not necessarily the same ones. So sometimes www.exapmle.com/shjk/ maybe missed, sometimes it maybe scraped.

Comment: In this case try to log the `response`s into a log file to see that you get back the same results as expected. It can be that the servers limit the amount of requests and you get an error message instead of your search results.